# SELECT DISTINCT multiple fields and show all

Tags: mysql, select, distinct, multiple-columns

I have table with this data:

```
id       name        hobbie          phone
------------------------------------------
1        user1       cooking         123
2        user1       cooking         123
3        user1       surfing         123
4        user3       drawing         456
```

I am trying to select all rows with the same "name" even though they have different hobbies. I tried `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM mytable;` which prints this:

```
 name 
------
 user1
 user3
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I distinct by name and hobbie at same time?
2. How can I output the hobbies and the phones too?

I want to output this with the query (the original without the repeated name and hobby):

```
id       name        hobbie          phone
------------------------------------------
1        user1       cooking         123
3        user1       surfing         123
4        user3       drawing         456
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at a dataset this small and optimization isn't really the concern, this would work

```
Select * from Users where id in (
(SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM Users GROUP BY name, hobbie)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` to get the output you want:

```
select min(id), name, hobbie,  phone
from table t
group by name, hobbie, phone;
```

What you describe doing is more like:

```
select min(id), name, hobbie, min(phone) as phone
from table t
group by name, hobbie;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1. You can do distinct by name and hobbie using the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, hobbie FROM mytable;
```

Answer 2. You can output hobbies and the phones too using following query

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id,
                      phone,
                      name,
                      hobbie
                      FROM mytable
                          GROUP BY phone,
                          name,
                          hobbie) t2 ON t.id = t2.id
```